# The underlying connection was closed error while using .Include on EF objects

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

Following line of code gives me an error saying "The underlying connection was closed".

```
return this.repository.GetQuery<Countries>().Include(g => g.Cities).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

But if I remove `.Include(g => g.cities)` it works fine.

this code is written in one of the operation in my WCF service, and I try to test it using WCF test client. I tried by calling this operation from MVC application also, and the same issue was occurring there too.
Also, i am using generic repository with entity framework

Repository code (only few important extract)

Constructor:

```
public GenericRepository(DbContext objectContext)
        {
            if (objectContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("objectContext");
            this._dbContext = objectContext;

            this._dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this._dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
```

GetQuery method:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        var entityName = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName);
    }
```

**Attempt#1**
Created following overloads in repository code:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>(params string[] includes) where TEntity : class
        {
            var entityName = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName);
                foreach(string include in includes)
                {
                    query = query.Include(include);
                }
            return query;
        }

public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params string[] includes) where TEntity : class
        {
            return GetQuery<TEntity>(includes).Where(predicate);
        }
```

WCF is now trying to execute following line of code:

```
return this.repository.GetQuery<Countries>("Cities").AsEnumerable().ToList()
```

But it still gives the same error of "The underlying connection was closed". I tested it in WCF test client. However, when I debug the repository code it shows the navigation object getting included in result, but the issue seems occurring while trying to pass the output to client (WCF test client, or any other client)

Comment: Can you post the repository code?

Comment: Repository code is too lengthy. So I am not sure if its best to post here. but yes, I have "ProxyCreationEnabled" set to False on DbContext instance. Let me know what information you would require

Comment: I believe that your entity framework context in the WCF service is being disposed once the WCF call returns, thus making the `Include` bomb on you. But I won't know for sure *unless you post the repository code*

Comment: I have included part of code. Please see edits, also do let me know if you require more information

Comment: Looking at your code I agree with @IronMan84 who has already stated why it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code you've now posted, I can conclude that, indeed, your DbContext is being closed at the end of the GetQuery method, and is thus failing when you try to use `include`. What you might want to do to solve it is to have an optional `params` variable for the `GetQuery` method that will take in some properties to be included, and just do the include right in the `GetQuery` method itself.

Comment: Thanks for observing and finding out the main reason.However, would like to know if there is any other way than changing GetQuery method? I have multiple overloads of this method, as well as there are some other methods too which returns Single result, multiple results, etc. Or what is the best practice to handle this in repository code?

Comment: One more question - how did you identify that the DbContext getting closed is the main issue? Because I have copied the repository code from another project, but it was using ObjectContext, and I changed mine to use DbContext. The .Include() in other project is working fine in that project.

Comment: To update more on this I tried the suggestion of IronMan84, and it still didn't work. Find my code under "Attempt#1" in edit of this question.