# Repository pattern with Entity Framework: How to make .Include work when the context is not alive?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using entity framework and generic repository in my project.

Following is one of the method in my repository.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            var entityName = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName);
        }
```

when i consume this method in my WCF service I want to Include certain navigation properties of that DbSet.
For example,

```
List<Countries> GetCountries()
{   
    return this.repository.GetQuery<Countries>().Include("Cities").AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

this should return all countries with cities populated in the navigation properties.

Currently this gives an error saying [The underlying connection was closed...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207066/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-error-while-using-include-on-ef-objects)

What changes you reckon to do to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: the problem is - it always give an error saying "The underlying connection was closed". If I remove "Include("Cities")" it works fine.

Comment: Why do you go through all the trouble of grabbing the underlying `ObjectContext`? Why not create a `DbSet<TEntity>` by calling `Set<TEntity>` on the `DbContext`? `DbSet` also has an `Include` method. There's a chance that your context is being destroyed before you call `GetCountries`.

Comment: Also, calling `AsEnumerable` isn't necessary if you're just going to call `ToList`.

Comment: I would actually guess that the problem is not directly related to the `Include` but the `City` entity you are including has navigation properties that the WCF serialization tries to load by lazy loading. But in your other question you have disabled lazy loading and proxy creation. Are they *really* disabled in your test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to EF 5.0 code generator template has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start with rewriting your GetQuery method to use DbContext directly.  the ObjectContext's GetQuery method is intended to use a SQL like syntax to query the data store.

You have a lot going on here you don't need.  Since you're starting with a DbContext derived class, simply use dbContext.Set() to retrieve the DbSet for the entity type, then use the Include( path ) method on the DbSet object.

Repository method:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>( string includePath = null )
{
    var dbSet = DbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    if( !string.IsNullOrWhitespace( includePath ) )
    {
        return dbSet.Include( includePath );
    }

    return dbSet;
}
```

usage:

```
List<Countries> GetCountries()
{   
    return this.repository.GetQuery<Countries>( "Cities" ).ToList();
}
```